# What is the difference between setting the path via editing /private/etc/paths vs ~/.profile?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, path, environment-variables, .profile

I just found out I can edit my `PATH` by editing `/etc/paths` or `/private/etc/paths`, or by putting `export PATH=$PATH:/a/path` in `~/.profile` or one of my other startup scrips.

Is there a difference between these methods? If so, is one method preferable to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One is system wide while the other is user-specific. If you want other users on your system to have some entries in their PATH, put them in the system wide configuration file. That's the difference.

The private folder is [mentioned here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=1760881&postcount=3).

Comment: Additionally, .profile only affects commands invoked via the command shell; /etc/paths has the potential to affect many more applications, some of which may be system utilities which rely upon the specific versions of programs in /etc/paths.